# Error with custom aggregate function for a cast() call in R reshape2

Tags: r, casting, aggregate, reshape, reshape2

I want to use R to summarize numerical data in a table with non-unique rownames to a result table with unique row-names with values summarized using a custom function. The summarization logic is: use the mean of values if the ratio of the maximum to the minimum value is < 1.5, else use median. Because the table is very large, I am trying to use the melt() and cast() functions in the [reshape2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/index.html) package.

```
# example table with non-unique row-names
tab <- data.frame(gene=rep(letters[1:3], each=3), s1=runif(9), s2=runif(9))
# melt
tab.melt <- melt(tab, id=1)
# function to summarize with logic: mean if max/min < 1.5, else median
summarize <- function(x){ifelse(max(x)/min(x)<1.5, mean(x), median(x))}
# cast with summarized values
dcast(tab.melt, gene~variable, summarize)
```

The last line of code above results in an error notice.

```
Error in vapply(indices, fun, .default) : 
  values must be type 'logical',
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'double'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

What am I doing wrong? Note that if the summarize function were to just return min(), or max(), there is no error, though there is the warning message about 'no non-missing arguments.' Thank you for any suggestion.

(The actual table I want to work with is a 200x10000 one.)

Answer (score 8):

Short answer:  provide a value for fill as follows
    acast(tab.melt, gene~variable, summarize, fill=0)

Long answer:
It appears your function gets wrapped as follows, before being passed to vapply in the vaggregate function (dcast calls cast which calls vaggregate which calls vapply):

```
fun <- function(i) {
    if (length(i) == 0) 
        return(.default)
    .fun(.value[i], ...)
}
```

To find out what .default should be, this code is executed

```
if (is.null(.default)) {
    .default <- .fun(.value[0])
}
```

i.e. .value[0] is passed to the function.  min(x) or max(x) returns Inf or -Inf on when x is numeric(0).  However, max(x)/min(x) returns NaN which has class logical.  So when vapply is executed

```
vapply(indices, fun, .default)
```

with the default value being is of class logical (used as template by vapply), the function fails when starting to return doubles.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the explanation. After providing a value for 'fill' in the dcast() call, I was able to get the code to work.

Answer (score 2):

dcast() tries to set the value of missing combination by default value.

you can specify this by fill argument, but if fill=NULL,
then the value returned by fun(0-lenght vector) (i.e., summarize(numeric(0)) here) is used as default.

please see ?dcast

then, here is a workaround:

```
 dcast(tab.melt, gene~variable, summarize, fill=NaN)
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this and helping.