# R dataframe sums of values that satisfy unique conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, levels, cumulative-sum

I have a dataset that contains the feeding data of 3 animals, consisting of the animals' tag ids (1,2,3), the type (A,B) and amount (kg) of feed given at each 'meal':

```
Animal   FeedType   Amount(kg)
Animal1     A         10
Animal2     B         7
Animal3     A         4
Animal2     A         2
Animal1     B         5
Animal2     B         6
Animal3     A         2
```

Using this, I want to be able to output the matrix below which has `unique('Animal')` as its rows, `unique('FeedType')` as its columns and the cumulative Feed Amount (kg) in the corresponding cells of the matrix.

```
         A   B
Animal1  10  5
Animal2  2   13
Animal3  6   0
```

I started coding a solution using two for loops as below:

```
dataframe = read_delim(input_url, header=TRUE, sep = ";")
animal_feed_matrix = matrix(0,nrow(unique('Animal')),nrow(unique('FeedType')))
for (i in 1:length(unique('Animal')) ){
 a= unique('Animal')[i]
  for (j in 1:length(unique('FeedType')) ){
    ft= unique('FeedType')[j]
    animal_feed_matrix[i,j] = sum(dataframe [(dataframe ['Animal']==a & dataframe ['FeedType']==ft),'Amount(kg)'])
  }
}
```

But I am aware that this is a very inefficient way to tackle the problem, (plus the code above needs to be completed in order to work). I am aware that R has **levels**, and **factors**, which I sense can solve the problem more elegantly.

**P.S:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698399/cumulative-count-of-unique-values-in-r) is somewhat similar to mine but even if the solution to my problem is contained within, it escapes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R:

```
out <- with(mydf, tapply(Amount, list(Animal, FeedType), sum))

         A  B
Animal1 10  5
Animal2  2 13
Animal3  6 NA
```

Then, to change `NA` to `0` (as in your example), just do:

```
out[is.na(out)] <- 0
```

Comment: Wow, that is quite powerful for a single line of code. Works like a charm! Just a brief question: the 'out' matrix is too sparse now because I have too many FeedType columns. How can I omit the FeedTypes that occur less than a certain numer of times? (e.g. I want to exclude column 'FeedTypeA' in 'out' if in 'mydf' it has occurred only once)

Comment: @Berkan I'd probably preprocess the original dataframe, excluding FeedTypes below a certain threshold before you run `by`. But, you can just remove columns from the resulting matrix with something like: `out[,!colnames(out)=="A",drop=FALSE]` (the `drop=FALSE` is unnecessary in large matrices, but prevents coercing the example matrix with just two columns to a vector).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with function `dcast()` from library `reshape2`.

```
library(reshape2)    
dcast(df,Animal~FeedType,sum,value.var="Amount")
   Animal  A  B
1 Animal1 10  5
2 Animal2  2 13
3 Animal3  6  0
```

Comment: Thank you, but the code gives an error: [Using Subsector as value column: use value.var to override.
Error in vaggregate(.value = value, .group = overall, .fun = fun.aggregate,  : 
  could not find function ".fun]. Also, in this one-liner where do I specify that the 'sum' is on Amount?

Comment: Function dcast() automatically use third column (if there is only three) to calculate sum. Updated example to more general solution with argument value.var= (to show which column to use). For your error - it seems that in your session sum is used as some variable. See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082792/error-message-running-the-example-from-the-reshape2-help-page)